How is "IsDisposed" boolean reliable when in a disposed class?
Some Microsoft classes implemenet an "IsDisposed" boolean that indicates that a class is disposed. I inherit some of these classes and sometimes start headless threads from them with a while(true) loop on the inside. The threads are set to terminate by checking if IsDisposed in the class is set to True. But how reliable is this? If the class is disposed, then wouldn't I lose access to the property 'IsDisposed' that sits inside the disposed class? Or will it remain undisposed because the Thread has a reference to the 'IsDisposed' property?

As long as you have a reference to the object, it will not be garbage collected and the values are still ok. No UB as in C++.

Disposal relates to freeing up unmanaged resources, not memory. So when an entity is disposed, the disposed properties/fields can no longer be accessed - but any properties and methods that don't access the disposed properties/fields directly or indirectly can still be used. The IsDisposed property, being a simple bool can therefore still be used after the containing entity has been disposed.

how reliable is this very. Dispose doesn't mean delete, it's a way to tell an object to release any resources it holds immediately. Objects are only deleted by the garbage collector. Buggy code could try to use an object even after it was Disposed though, so important classes take explicit measures to prevent this. Imagine eg a connection object declared at the top of a long method, that gets closed by line 745 at region 9 but then line 1234 at region 13 tries to execute a command using the same variable (or field)

You could handle an ObjectDisposedException

is ObjectDisposedException possible here? Like the above comments say "but any properties and methods that don't access the disposed properties/fields directly or indirectly can still be used" and " being a simple bool can therefore still be used after the containing entity has been disposed", I wouldn't expect a "ObjectDisposedException".

One thing you need to see is, the Dispose method can be called by any other classes and it is not only by runtime. so having IsDisposedhelps to not call Dispose method multiple times. for example the case you mentioned is exactly for that, they are waiting for other part of the app to call dispose method and set the IsDispose=true.


The threads are set to terminate by checking if IsDisposed in the class is set to True. But how reliable is this?

It's not reliable, unless the class is explicitly documented to be thread-safe. Accessing any member of a non thread-safe class in a multithreaded environment without synchronization is a technical violation, and results in a program with undefined behavior. From a quick look at the documentation, most classes that are equipped with an IsDisposed property are not documented to be thread-safe. For example the class System.Windows.Forms.Control (and the 20+ classes that derive from it) is documented to have only a few thread-safe members, and the IsDisposed is not one of them:

Only the following members are thread safe: BeginInvoke, EndInvoke, Invoke, InvokeRequired, and CreateGraphics if the handle for the control has already been created.

So reading the IsDisposed of this class in any thread other than the UI thread (the thread that instances of this class are created) is neither reliable nor allowed.
On the other hand the System.Runtime.Caching.ChangeMonitor is documented to be completely thread-safe:

This type is thread safe.

So you are allowed to check the IsDisposed of this class in any thread without synchronization, and doing so is reliable.
For classes that are mentioning nothing about thread safety in their documentation, you should assume that they are not thread-safe.

While I understand reading a field is not inherently thread safe, what I am referring to here is the reliability of the value when reading it from an object that has been disposed. So it's a bit less about thread safety and a bit more about the dispose mechnics.

To expand on your answer tho, why would a bool be thread-unsafe if read from a single thread (not the main one) without any locks, especially one that doesn't rely on up-to-date info? Yes, you might read outdated info, but bool reads and writes are by implementation atomic, so I don't see how this is thread unsafe in this scenario (tho I get the warning about a multi-threaded scenario where the value must always be accurate)

@EduardG the Dispose is all about semantics, and nothing about mechanics. There is no special treatment for a method named Dispose by the the .NET runtime or the C# compiler. The author of a class is free to implement the Dispose however they like, as far as the mechanics are concerned. Of course developers are highly motivated to adhere to the patterns and semantics associated with this method, because otherwise their APIs would unintuitive and confusing to use.

@EduardG properties in C# are camouflaged methods. When you read a property, you invoke the get accessor of this property, which might include all kind of code. If the documentation doesn't specify that either the class as a whole or the specific member in particular is thread-safe, it means that the author didn't implement this member having thread-safety in mind. So nobody knows what behavior will emerge if the property is read from multiple threads without synchronization. And we, as engineers, are not supposed to build stuff based on the rolling of a dice.
